# select("svg") - difference between two alternatives

Tags: html, d3.js

I am a bit perplexed with this please. I thought they would be equivalent expressions but apparently they are not. The following are the starting lines of a piece of code that does a pie chart. That works fine and the transform moves the chart at the centre of the svg

```
var width = 280,
    height = 200,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var svg = d3.select("#pie")
    .select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

However I was trying to move `width` and `height` outside the js code and into the index.html file. The code below was supposed to do the trick but I am missing something here. The chart ends up centered at the top-left corner of the svg. Being a pie chart you eventually get only one quadrant visible. I have double checked and both `width` and `height` have the desired values. That's the relevant part in the html page:

```
<div class="chart-stage" id="pie">
      <svg width="280" height="200"></svg>
</div>
```

I must be doing something wrong with the svg chaining I guess

```
var svg = d3.select("#pie")
            .select("svg")

var width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height")

var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

svg.attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

Comment: The selection `svg` contains different things in each example. In the first one `svg` is a selection of a `g` as `.append("g")` returns a selection holding the newly appended `g`. In the second one `svg` is a selection of the svg (and that svg happens to hold a `g`). If you append things to `svg` in in the first code block it appends to the transformed `g` and in the other it appends siblings to the transformed `g` by appending to the svg itself.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I think I got the idea but not quite. So if I set width/height with something like width = +d3.select("#pie").select("svg").attr("width") and then continue as usual as shown in the first piece of code (ignoring of course var width 
= 280) since we just set that, is that sensible please? (it works though...)

Comment: Not sure if I quite follow the comment - but to make the second code block result in the same outcome as the first you could use `svg = svg.append("g").attr("transform",...` *(No need to set height/width of the svg with `svg.attr("width",width).attr("height",height)` they are already set in the svg element's attribute tags)*. This way the selection `svg` refers to the `g` element, as in the first code block, and anything appended with `svg.append()` will be translated to the center as a child of that `g`.

Comment: Ah yes! ofcourse. Many thanks! (Emm, how do I accept that as an answer now?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection in the first and second code blocks is different. In the first `svg` refers to a selection of a `g` element that has a transform. In the second `svg` refers to a selection of the `svg` element. *This `svg` element contains a child `g` with a transform but using `svg.append()` will append a sibling to that `g`*:

```
var svg = d3.select("#pie")       // return a selection of the element with id pie
    .select("svg")                // return a selected of the svg
    .attr("width", width)         // return the same svg
    .attr("height", height)       // return the same svg
    .append("g")                  // return a selected g element
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");  // return the selected g element.
```

Here `svg` is a selected `g` element.

```
var svg = d3.select("#pie")   // return a selection of the element with id pie
            .select("svg");    // return a selection of the svg
```

Here `svg` is a selected `svg` - once the initial chaining is done, subsequent actions: `svg.attr().append()` do not change the variable's definition.

To make the second example's outcome equivilant to the first example you could redefine the `svg` variable to be  a selection of the child `g`:

```
var svg = d3.select("#pie")
        .select("svg")

var width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height")

svg = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

Though, it might be more clear to call that variable something like `g` since it is a selection of a `g` and not a `svg`.